# How to save a new excel file with multiple sheets and with vba scripts that runs in those sheets

Tags: excel, vba

- EDITED

Hi I am trying to save a file from a parent file which has filtered data in a sheet and in the other sheet if values of some cells are changed, in turn changes the value in the first sheet.
It isnt working properly since I changed it to take only filtered data instead of using normal s3.Copy instead of xLvisible and to get the VBA codes on the sheets as well?
Here's the code I am using, thanks:

```
Sub ExportXLSX()

'exports desired sheet to new XLSX file

Dim userpath As String
    userpath = Environ("UserProfile")
    
Dim sToday As String
    
Dim s3 As Worksheet
Set s3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
Dim MyPath As String

Dim MyFileName As String

Dim DateString As String

sToday = s3.Range("B3").Value

DateString = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hh_mm_ss_AM/PM")

MyFileName = DateString & "_" & "File_2024_" & sToday & ".xlsm"


s3.copy
's3.Range("A8:BF9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select the loaction and click ok!"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = userpath & " \ Desktop \ "
    '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker
    If .Show = 1 Then GoTo NextCode
MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

End With

NextCode:

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
.Close False

End With

End Sub
```

The old version didnt have FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled but it isnt the main concern because while saving user will have the option to declare the file. What I cant figure out is how to copy 3 sheets with their VBA code in the new Macro file with filtered data, this code works if I copy the whole sheets without filtering but I cannot use s3.**Range**("A8:BF9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy and I cannot get filtered data from copying the entire sheet. Also my copy range starts with Row 7.

Can I do it in any way with .Attachments.Add FileName?

I apologise if it seems like a stupid question, I am stuck at this from yesterday.

Comment: Instead of `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` you have to use `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` when saving.

Comment: Thank you I tried, edited, S3.copy just copies the whole sheet not just visible rows, S3.Range("A7:A9999").SpecialCells.Copy not working, it just opens a file with no sheets, doesnt take my sheets because of the range I am copying

Comment: You add `.xlsm` to the file name and then check if `.xlsm` is in the filename - you know it is.  You just added it.  You're also checking if it exists by matching the last four characters of the filename to `.xlsm` which is five characters, so you'll always end up with files ending with `.xlsm.xlsm`

Comment: If you press Cancel in the `FileDialog` then you tell it to jump to `NextCode`, but by pressing Cancel `MyPath` will not get a value but the line after `NextCode` uses `MyPath` to save the file irrespective of whether you pressed Cancel or not.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind to check .Show value correctly, edited the code to stop duplicacy of .xlsm, for .Show i thought if we give 1, it's modal which i used for FileSave, I had <>1 because I thought when cancel, it returns -1, I edited, am I missing something even now? Thank you for your help!